# What is the difference between livy.rsc.jars and livy.repl.jars?

Tags: apache-spark, livy

I'm working on Jupyter Notebooks using sparkmagic kernel (spark-scala) which relies on Apache Livy to run spark jobs.

I'm currently trying to understand the options to create sessions with user-provided dependencies i.e., jars.

I know in Jupyter I can do something like:

```
%%configure -f
{"kind": "spark", 
 "executorMemory": "2G", 
 "executorCores": 4, 
 "jars": ["/path/to/library1.jar",
         "/path/to/library2"]}
```

But then I noticed other options in `LIVY_HOME/conf/livy.conf`, particularly `livy.resc.jars` and `livy.repl.jars` but I believe the descriptions are not very specific or I'm unable to find the actual difference between these.

I guess if they are separated it's for something, but what exactly?